# How to properly use callback refs to get selected values in Typescript?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript

I am trying to use the up-to-date method to get a value from a Select element via React but I seem to be getting all kinds of errors. I originally used string refs, but it seems like that is now considered legacy.

```
class Base extends React.Component<any, any> {
    constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.candInput = React.createRef();
    this.state = {name: '', ns:'', svc: '', base:'', cand:[]};
}
handleAddCand = (e) => {
        if(!this.state.cand.includes(this.candInput.current.value) &&
            this.state.base !== (this.candInput.current.value)){

            this.setState((prevState) => ({
            cand: [...prevState.cand, this.candInput.current.value],
            }));
        }
}
```

And the returned components that use the ref is placed like:

```
<Select
    id="ns-select"
    labelText="Namespace"
    helperText="..."
    ref={this.candInput}
/>
<Button
    onClick={this.handleAddCand}
>
    Add
</Button>
```

For some reason I keep getting errors that claim that candInput doesn't exist? The compiler err msg is:

`Property 'candInput' does not exist on type 'Base'.`

And the error that ref is not a property available for this particular element. The element is a imported Carbon Component, but I can't tell if that's the core issue. The error message is:

`Property 'ref' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & SelectProps & { children?: ReactNode; }'.`

My react version is 16.12 and the carbon component version is 7.10, so I definitely have updated modules. Any pointers or help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I ran into this issue earlier, it's because TypeScript doesn't like class properties being declared in the `constructor` for the first time. I got around this by adding a line to the class, above the `constructor`, like this `candInput: React.RefObject`

Comment: @Ramesh I didn't misspell it, the "Base" refers to the custom React component class. And the error stems from `this.candInput = React.createRef();`

Comment: @awarrier99 I see, I resolved that error by placing `candInput = React.createRef<HTMLSelectElement>();` before the constructor!

Comment: @avhhh Good to hear you've solved your question! If I could give you this piece of advice though: it's better to use controlled components than uncontrolled ones if possible. I think it even may be possible to have a controlled `select` element while adding options dynamically to it.

Comment: @RobertMoore That is possible, but I just thought it would be more user friendly if I have a button that tells the user explicitly that at every change they are adding to the list of options. If I make it controlled, then it would be difficult to make `<Select>` have a multiselect feature.